# Are memes allowed on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, rules, memes

I know that emojis are not allowed in the Q&A, because they are considered distractions, but they are allowed in the comments on Stack Overflow.

Let's suppose that I am answering a question and to avoid people accidentally copy-pasting a dangerous command, I want to include this GIF image instead of a well formatted text:

[image: Deleting everything]

A moment ago, I accidentally posted this question with an offensive meme to a community and deleted it:

[image]

I assume that if it is currently not allowed, and allowing it may require new rules.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your self-deleted question https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384506/336163 .

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wanted to reset the downvotes so increase the possibility of people answering the question. The previous question is deleted. How can this one be duplicate with a deleted post?

Comment: Resetting the downvotes is not a valid approach to getting your feature-request accepted.

Comment: And no, such 'memes' are ill advised. They are very poor for screenreaders and searchability.

Comment: Please don't delete and repost the same question just to get rid of its downvotes. Downvotes don't actually reduce the possibility of a question getting answered, especially here on Meta, but we have them for a reason.

Comment: Better now,  but as others said, still not a good idea to use in posts. More fitting place would be chat.

Comment: @Mast Well, I panic-deleted the previous one because the meme i used was accidentally offensive. It had -4 votes. I am not deleting this one with currently 7 downvotes and I assume that this information disproves your assumption. And thanks for the information about screenreaders and searchability. That is the comment we need.

Comment: Honestly, I found the meme in your previous post hilarious but these ones offensive. That's why memes are a bad idea - someone is going to be offended regardless.

Comment: Agreed with others, memes are a bad idea and, aside from the issues they create for searchability and accessibility, they are inevitably going to be offensive to _some group of people_, sarcasm may be missed by others, and the whole thing will be simply not understood by those who might lack context. Let's not go out of our way to try to turn Q & A into Facebook.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I am writing a self-answer with all the information you provided.

Comment: I have made no assumptions in those comments. All statements there are based on experience.

Comment: @Mast I didn't even know that if it was allowed or not, so didn't "reset downvotes for making a feature-request accepted." This was your assumption even though I stated why I deleted it in the question and another reason in my comment. It would be dumb, probably the same people downvoted again already. 

It was a 'panic-delete' because it was considered offensive. I wanted to avoid that because it was not my intention. After posting the second one, I realized that I could have edited the previous one. 

I added feature-request tag because it was suggested in the box.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/), not StackOverflow.

Comment: `I wanted to reset the downvotes ...`, you don't "reset" the downvotes by deleting them, you hide them and get the reputation returned; but it comes at a cost, it puts you closer to a question ban. --- `And thanks for the information about screenreaders and searchability.`, that's not correct, by filling in an image description (in compliance with the FAQ) most screenreaders will annunciate the contents of the image correctly. Some people respond to images (and red circles) better than without, and some do not. --- Use good images sparingly  and annotate them only if you do so correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memes are a bad idea for multiple reasons.

Since they are not in text format, currently, most of the screen readers cannot process them and they cannot be indexed well for search engines, as [pointed out by Mast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384508/are-memes-allowed-in-stack-exchange-sites?noredirect=1#comment1282537_384508).

Every meme could be offensive for different groups of people because they are made with intention of making people laugh via a way that is not directly understood, making most of them ironic and sarcastic, as [pointed out by Robert Colombia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384508/are-memes-allowed-in-stack-exchange-sites?noredirect=1#comment1282542_384508)

A question or an answer should preferably be clear and straightforward. Memes are sometimes complex, and tend to be sarcastic and can be easily misunderstood from different perspectives. They simply don't fit to a Q&A platform. Making the platform turn into e.g. Facebook is not preferable, as [pointed by Aaron Bertrand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384508/are-memes-allowed-in-stack-exchange-sites?noredirect=1#comment1282543_384508).

With all of the above reasons, memes requiring more storage space than text in the servers are not even worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5):

I found the meme in your [previously deleted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384506/336163) to be hilarious even though someone else found it offensive, but I find the ones in this one to be offensive. That's why memes are a bad idea - someone is going to be offended regardless.

Comment: I watched a video of a guy dressed as a Mexican and asking questions to young people if it was offensive. They all found it offensive with their explanations. Later on, he visited real Mexican people and repeated the question. They loved him and his costume. I get your point well and I am upvoting your answer.